# Adding an "s" after a quote

Tags: quotations, quotation-marks, multiplicity

I have a basic question,

Say I have a quote, ***"I told you so"***

Now let's say that quote has been said to me many times.
  How would I write this in a sentence such as the following?

The "I told you so"(multiple) I was told as a kid didn't help.

Comment: You could try to pluralize, but it's probably better to rephrase. The many times [whoever] said "I told you so" when I was a kid didn't help."

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Brian Hitchcock's comment above that there is no elegant way to pluralize a quotation while retaining the quotation marks. If you are committed to keeping the quotation marks, your choices boil down to, on the one hand, adding an -*s* after the close quotation mark:

> The "I told you so"s I was told as a kid didn't help.

or in some cases an -*es* after the close quotation mark:

> Thousands of "I am Spartacus"es rang through the air.

and on the other hand moving the plural aspect of the quotation outside the words of the quotation altogether, as with:

> The countless repetitions of "I told you so" that I heard as a kid didn't help.

and:

> Thousands of shouts of "I am Spartacus!" rang through the air.

I can't imagine that, given a choice, many readers would vote for the *-s/-es* option.

---

Another option (at least in the "I told you so" instance) might be to remove the quotation marks and italicize the phrase, adding an apostrophe-*s* at the end to signify the plural:

> The *I told you so's* I heard as a kid didn't help.

Comment: If you are a fan of Truss's, she recommends '_The I told you so_'s I heard as a kid didn't help.' where the apostrophe-s is not italicised.